# finding specific values within a table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula which gives me the far right column for each ID when it isn't N/A. However, when there are duplicate ID's (for example 2 and 3 below have been duplicated) I want the furthest down ID and the far right column.

So for ID 2 I want 2.2, and for ID 3 I want 3.2

```
ID     Value     Value
1      1.1       1.2
2      2.1       2.1.R
2      2.1.R     2.2
3      3.1       3.1
3      3.2       N/A
```

I have tried using a V look up as follows

```
  =VLOOKUP(E5,H:M,6,0)
```

This always gives me the far right column and also doesn't take into account duplicates, I know to make it so it gives me the second the last column when it is N/A I could use some sort of IF statement, however, I have no idea how to make the formula consider duplicates and choose the furthest down ID

Comment: When you say Lowest you mean the furthest down? because 2.1 is lower than 2.2 numerically.

Comment: the furthest down ID value

Comment: In your example the bottom right number is the largest number, is that always true?

Comment: Can you share details of what you have tried / got working so far?  In this way people can help to resolve this specific problem for you, but also you'll be better equipped to solve similar problems yourself in future

Comment: not necessarily - should I edit my example to randomise numbers, in my actual work it is not always a number, i.e. could be 3.2.2R in the bottom right

Comment: yes, make sure your example shows all conditions, other wise you may get the wrong answer, and we will have wasted our time and your time.

Comment: also are they always sorted on ID?

Comment: yes, always sorted on ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(A:C,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)+COUNTIF(A:A,E2)-1,0),LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISERROR(INDEX(A:C,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)+COUNTIF(A:A,E2)-1,0)))),COLUMN($A$1:$C$1)))
```

[image]

---

If `N/A` is text and not the error `#N/A` then use:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(A:C,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)+COUNTIF(A:A,E2)-1,0),LOOKUP(2,1/(INDEX(A:C,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)+COUNTIF(A:A,E2)-1,0)<>"N/A"),COLUMN($A$1:$C$1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Is N/A a typed value or the Error?  If not the error and a Typed value, will it be only `N/A` that we need to worry about?

Comment: it is a typed value "n/a" to be exact. and yes it will always be n/a. apologise for not making that clear

Comment: also, would it be possible for you to break up the code and explain it? apologise for the inconvenience but this will help me understand it better

Comment: nifty tool on the formula tab there is a evaluate formula that will do the formula step by step.  `INDEX(A:C,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)+COUNTIF(A:A,E2)-1,0)` returns the last row with that id.  Then the LOOKUP will find the last cell that satisfies the `<>"N/A"` because it looks for where 2>1 which the formula returns and will return the column number to the outer index.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help!

Comment: I was just wondering why this formula only works if the data sets starts in column one, i.e. if I insert a blank column the formula adjusts for the column however the formula no longer works

Comment: The column References should always start in column A even if blank.  It has to do with the LOOKUP returning the column number when INDEX wants a relative reference number.  When the index starts in column A then the column number is the relative reference number, if not it will be off.